# How to include JSF template in different folder

Tags: templates, jsf, layout, facelets

i've been searching in all section of this forum and still don't get an answer about my problem.

My problem is how to include JSF template that located in different folder. Here's my folder structure and file list.

```
/WEB-INF
login.xhtml
/template
-----layout.xhtml
/home
-----homefile.xhtml
-----/user
----------userfile.xhtml
```

What im trying to do is to using template under /template folder on `homefile.xhtml` and `userfile.xhtml`. I already try this following code

```
<ui:composition template="template/layout.xhtml">
</ui:compostion>
```

But its not working. I got error that "can't find resources "template/layout.xhtml">.
If i use that code in `login.xhtml` its working fine.

Any idea how to do it ?
One of the solution is make another `/template/layout.xhtml` inside home folder, but i think its not the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a slash in front of your template location like this:

```
<ui:composition template="/template/layout.xhtml">
</ui:compostion>
```

This should work. The location `template/layout.xhtml` is relative to the "current folder", which will mean JSF will try to load `/home/template/layout.xhtml`.

Comment: But OP would better put template files in WEB-INF folder to prevent direct access from end users.